# Excel VBA - Comparing values consisting of data from two columns, with two columns on different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, compare

I've created an Excel document for Serial number based Inventory. The document consist of four sheets, Main, Storage, Incoming-history and Outgoing-history. 
On the main sheet I have five columns: "Date", "Travel document", "Equipment type", "Serial Number" and "Comments".

I've created a VBA macro for transferring the data (multiple rows with serial numbers) from the main sheet, to corresponding columns on the "Storage" and Incoming/outgoing. So far so good.

The problem occurs when I'm trying to code the VBA for removing rows from the Storage sheet. What I want to do, is comparing the columns With Equipment Type AND Serial number from the Main Sheet, With the corresponding two columns on the Storage Sheet. I've managed, With some help from looking at other codes on this forum, to make a vba that compares the Serial Number Column on both sheets, then delete the Equal rows. 
Using this code:

```
Sub Utmeld()
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long

With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

With Sheets("storage")
      .Select


    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView


    .DisplayPageBreaks = False


    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row


    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

         With .Cells(Lrow, "F")
         If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Value, Sheets("Main").Range("F1:F200"), 0)) Then .EntireRow.Delete
         End With

      Next Lrow

End With

ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

End Sub
```

The problem is, however, I might stumble upon different euipment types With same Serial Numbers, so I need to include the E column in the comparisment. Simple Pseudocode: If columns E & F on Main Sheet = Columns E & F on Storage Sheet Then Delete Entire Row.

Any help on how to solve this, is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Retain your original script but change only this part

```
Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

If Worksheets("main").Cells(Lrow, 1) = Worksheets("storage").Cells(Lrow, 1) Then

Worksheets("storage").activate
Cells(Lrow, 1).EntireRow.Delete
Worksheets("main").activate
End If

Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :) But running this macro only generates an error "Run Time Error 1004 Application Defined or Object Defined Error" while highlighting the line: "If Worksheets("main").Cells(i, 1) = Worksheets("storage").Cells(i, 1) Then"

Comment: Oh because i is not declared as variable yet. I'll edit the code and you can try again

Comment: I've changed the i to Lrow. It should work this time :)

Comment: Thanks, no errors this time :) But the script deleted all rows in the Storage sheets, and some of the columns on the main sheet, regardless of cell values!

Comment: Isn't that what u wanted? “: If columns E & F on Main Sheet = Columns E & F on Storage Sheet Then Delete Entire Row.”

Comment: Not quite, I can see how that sentence was more confusing than clarifying. To narrow it down : On the "Main" sheet I have two columns that need to be compared to what's already on the "Storage" sheet. Column E defines what kind of Device, and column F contains the Serial number. If there's a match With the combination of Device AND Serial number on "Storage" sheet, the line should be removed from Storage.

Comment: So u want the duplicate in storage sheet to be removed, but retain the entry in main sheet.. then from my code just remove the worksheets ("main").....Line. I've edit the code again and u may try again

Comment: Thanks again. Still no cigar, though. This line deletes the entire Storage sheet.

Comment: how is that possible? the line says Worksheets("storage").Cells(Lrow, 1).EntireRow.Delete..... however, I'll edit this code again and let me know if it works now.